# How to verify if a list of strings contains only digit characters?

Tags: string, list, haskell

I would like to have a function that return `True` if my list of strings contain only digit characters and `False` otherwise.

For exemple :
`["1", "2", "3", "24", "101"]`
The function return `True`
If not :
`["1", "2", "a"]`
The function return `False`.

Comment: Your post would improve, if you show us what you have tried and why it failed.

Comment: Is an empty string OK or not ?

Answer (score 4):

[`isDigit :: Char -> Bool`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-Char.html#v:isDigit) returns `True` if the character is 0 to 9.

[`all :: Foldable t => (a -> Bool) -> t a -> Bool`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:all) determines whether all elements of the structure satisfy the predicate.

So `all isDigit` returns `True` if a `String` contains only digits. Therefore `all (all isDigits)` returns `True` if a list of `String`s contain only digits.

```
import Data.Char ( isDigit )

onlyDigits :: [String] -> Bool
onlyDigits = all (all isDigit)
```

Note that `all` always returns `True` when applied to the empty list `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

```hs
import Data.Char

listOfStrings = ["1", "2", "3", "24", "101"]

checkListOfStringsAreNums :: [String] -> Bool
checkListOfStringsAreNums listOfStrings = foldr (&&) True isElemsAreNums
 where
  isElemsAreNums :: [Bool]
  isElemsAreNums = fmap isStringOfDigits listOfStrings

  isStringOfDigits :: String -> Bool
  isStringOfDigits = all isDigit
```

Comment: The `foldr` can be replaced by `all`.

Comment: note that this approach will reject numbers with decimal points or minus signs - which may or may not be what the OP intends.

Comment: Well - then that should've been asked. Otherwise server needs to have pregognition when the client not send a request yet.
If we would go into "what numbers could be" - it is an endless topic. The question is formulated for positive integers.

To give the general answer we need to parse: negative, scientific notation (exponentials), floating point (preferably with respect to possible localization, aka where I am at the `,` is used for separation), account for GMP-sized case, {rational, piano, complex, quarterion} numbers, which are obviously also numbers.